# Many Servers One Client

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

I have 4 Servers with the same functionality running on the same machine (return random int after random amount of time)

I have one client that runs the function in every server waits the return and prints all four numbers.

how can this be achieved with wcf?

Comment: This isn't a particularly clear question: do you mean you _have_ four servers, or you _would like_ four servers? Do you _have_ the client or is that what you would like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your question is  correct, You can host the same service with four different end points on the same server and your client will have the reference to all the four. Implement an "async" method on the client side to call the Function on four end points and print all of them once you got the result from all the four.

Small sample from online for async implementation -- https://gist.github.com/1223284